# How to show my flat’s place in the apartment

Tags: meaning

Let’s say that I live in a apartment with 10 storey. While I was passing in front of it with my friend he asked me in which floor I live . If I told him sentence below would it be grammatically correct ? I asked this question for a specifical situation .

> It is two story below the flat with lights on.

Comment: It is two **floors** or **storeys** (AmE **stories**) below the flat with **its** lights on.

Comment: Why should I say “its”? There are perhaps three or four rooms with lights on.( from the guardian)

Comment: It's not wrong to leave it out, but sentences without articles and pronouns are a mark of English learners.

Comment: Got it . Thank you so much.

Comment: Also possible is, “...below the flat with **the** lights on.”  I should mention too that you have confused the use of “apartments” and “flats”. You can say “a flat in a block of flats” *or* “an apartment in an apartment building” but it is unusual to mix the terminology: “a flat in an apartment building”.

Comment: @Weather Vane. Indeed, leaving out pronouns and articles is, from our perspective “a mark of English learners”. But I personally wouldn’t advise English learners to avoid doing so merely so they are not “marked” as learners (as if that needs to be avoided when they *are* learners). I’d say that more idiomatic usage, including using pronouns and articles like native speakers use them, makes a learner more easily understood and more easily integrated into ordinary conversations, etc. It is one way they can improve the quality of their communication in English.